# R which function displays wrong row numbers

Tags: r

I am trying to save the row number for values equal to one, for every column seperatly in a matrix (matx). The matrix should contain 0's for every other object. It somehow worked to give me numbers which are just a little bit smaller (1 value smaller in the beginning, two and three later on), but not the right values. The original matrix has just values of 0 and 1.
My try:

```
matx<-replicate(n=100,rbinom(n= 250, size=1, prob = 0.01))

maty<-apply(!matx, 2, function(x) ifelse(x==0,
         which(x %in% 1),
         x==0))
```

also tried:

```
maty<-apply(!matx, 2, function(x) ifelse(x>0, as.integer(rownames(matx)), 0))
```

The second attempt just leaves me with NA's and 0's instead of the row number.

Comment: matx from matx<-replicate(n=100,rbinom(n= 250, size=1, prob = 0.01))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to replace the '1s' (in the binary matrix) with the corresponding row numbers leaving the '0s' as such, we can can `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get the row/column index of non-zero numbers, use that index to replace the `1s` with the `row index` column from 'ind'.  Here, I created a copy of 'matx' (ie. 'maty') in case the original matrix is needed.

```
maty <- matx
ind <- which(matx!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)
maty[ind] <- ind[,1]
maty
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    2    0    0
#[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
#[4,]    4    4    0    0    0
#[5,]    5    0    0    5    0
#[6,]    6    6    6    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    7    0
#[8,]    8    0    8    8    0
#[9,]    9    9    9    9    0
#[10,]   0    0    0   10    0
```

and original matrix

```
 matx
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    0    1    0    0    0
 #[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
 #[3,]    1    1    1    0    0
 #[4,]    1    1    0    0    0
 #[5,]    1    0    0    1    0
 #[6,]    1    1    1    0    0
 #[7,]    0    0    0    1    0
 #[8,]    1    0    1    1    0
 #[9,]    1    1    1    1    0
 #[10,]   0    0    0    1    0
```

**NOTE:**  This could be also used for non-numeric elements

Or a `base R` modification of `apply` solution in @eipi's post would be

```
 apply(matx, 2,function(x)  ifelse(x!=0, seq_along(x), 0) )
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
matx <- matrix(sample(0:1, 10*5, replace=TRUE), nrow=10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly! Can't figure out why my which function didn't do it.

Comment: @Simon the `which` part is not the same length as `x` in your code.   May be `apply(matx, 2,function(x)  ifelse(x!=0, seq_along(x), 0) )`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that @akrun's interpretation is correct (it's also how I read the question) you can also use the `row` function:

```
matx * row(matx)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
#  [2,]    0    0    2    0    0
#  [3,]    3    3    3    0    0
#  [4,]    4    4    0    0    0
#  [5,]    5    0    0    5    0
#  [6,]    6    6    6    0    0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    7    0
#  [8,]    8    0    8    8    0
#  [9,]    9    9    9    9    0
# [10,]    0    0    0   10    0
```

Comment: Or `matx*(1:nrow(matx))`, just to save some memory.

Comment: @nicola, very true, especially for large input matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If your original matx is purely 0s and 1s then this show work:

```
maty <- matx * row(matx)
```

an example:

```
> matx # stealing from akrun
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    1    1    0    0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    0
 [5,]    1    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    1    1    1    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0
 [8,]    1    0    1    1    0
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    1    0
> matx * row(matx)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    2    0    0
 [3,]    3    3    3    0    0
 [4,]    4    4    0    0    0
 [5,]    5    0    0    5    0
 [6,]    6    6    6    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    7    0
 [8,]    8    0    8    8    0
 [9,]    9    9    9    9    0
[10,]    0    0    0   10    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using `apply`:

```
library(zoo) # For index function

apply(matx, 2, function(x) ifelse(x==1, index(x), 0))
```